# Deepin Linux stuck on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, deepin

Sometime my laptop successfully shutdown but sometimes no, it stuck on Deepin Linux Logo.

After edit `quiet splash` to `acpi=force` in `/etc/default/grub` I can figure out my problem is stuck exactly at Stopping Disk.

Here is `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`/usr/bin/lsb_release -d -s 2>/dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1366x768"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
```

Here is the image

[image: Stuck at Stopping Disk]

How I can diagnose what causing this stuck problem, and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this patch should work for you if I correctly understood your problem -

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=792552

Comment: How to I apply patch? I'm using Deepin, is this compatible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Deepin 15.4, you shouldn't update the system at all.
Check your hard drive thoroughly for errors. If you didn't forget to mention other issues, this might be a hardware failure.

Comment: What software you suggest to check hard drive for error?

Comment: `sudo apt install -y smartmontools && smartctl --all --test=conveyance`

Comment: Append `/dev/sda/` to above line of commands, if your machine only has a single HDD.